# MySQL custom order by clause

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 125 records, the primary key is the id field.

I'm trying to output the rows depending on how the user submits the new order via a web form.

For example, if the form data comes back as `3,54,32,112,99`, I build the following query:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=3 OR id=54 OR id=32 OR id=112 OR id=99`

I need the output to be row 3 first, then row 54, 32 etc... But instead it just uses the default `ORDER BY` clause and orders the output in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
         WHERE id IN (3,54,32,112,99)
         ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,'3,54,32,112,99')
```